# Debugger Not Working in ViewModel of Knockout Code

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

There is viewmodel.js file containing knockout.js code. On here there is need to debug the code @time of application running in web-browser. I have putted down debugger in b/w of code:

```
function getAnnouncements() {

    if (vm.page() <= vm.pageCount() || vm.pageCount() === -0) {

        debugger;

        vm.hasLoaded(false);
        vm.showLoading(true);
 }
```

When trying to debug this code, inspect window of web-browser is not triggering debugger.

Comment: Which probably means the `if` block never executes... Put a breakpoint or `debugger` statement *above* the `if` statement and check the values of `vm.page()` and `vm.pageCount()`. Why is there a `-0`?

Comment: @user3297291, If block executes every time, also i have tried with putting  debugger statement above the if statement. and -0 is used for some logic. However not succeed.

Comment: Make sure you have the developer console open when loading the page. The `debugger` statement only works if you're already debugging (at least that's how it works in Chrome).

Comment: Yes, I am looking into it in developer console of browser, I have tried with IE, Mozilla, Chrome also @user3297291

Comment: Add debugger above the if and see if the if-returns true

Comment: I have checked it by using console.log('Check debugging') as code is reaching on here or not, as this message is showing in browser's developer console, then it proves that code is reaching here , however not succeed. @SalminSkenderovic